# Is iPad Pro 10.5” (2017) only wifi or it needs to be wifi + cellular?

Tags: ipad

I am looking on eBay for an iPad Pro 10.5” model and in the original Apple website it clearly says that both Pro versions 10.5” and 12.9” comes with Wi-Fi + Cellular connectivity. But many of the sellers in their descriptions point out that it is Wi-Fi only. I do not understand - should the iPad Pro 10.5” come with Wi-Fi + cellular or only Wi-Fi?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I've provided an answer to your question, but have also edited your question to remove aspects that would have made it off-topic for being too broad and/or primarily opinion-based. You may want to refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad Pro, regardless of whether it's the 10.5" or 12.9" size, comes in two main configurations - one with Wi-Fi only and one with both Wi-Fi + Cellular.

The reason many of the sellers are pointing out that the model they're selling is Wi-Fi only is because that's the configuration they're selling.

For more detailed information I refer you to the [specs](https://www.apple.com/ipad-pro/specs/) provided on Apple's website. You'll see that there are details for both the Wi-Fi models and the Wi-Fi + Cellular models. For example, you'll see differences listed under Size and Weight and so on.

Comment: Thanks the answer. May I know why some sellers do not or can’t provide EAN number?

Comment: The only way to be 100% sure as to why a particular seller won't/cannot provide an EAN is to ask them. I know in some cases the seller won't actually have the item in their possession (e.g. it's located at a warehouse, they actually organise delivery from a 3rd party, etc). However, if you wanted to know for sure prior to purchase, you'd have to ask them directly.

Comment: Actually, I do not need the EAN, I was just thinking that maybe they can’t provide them only for fake products.